# Initializing class attribute Python

Tags: python, class, attributes, pygame

I have a following program with Pygame:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((600,800))
gameExit = False
x=0
y=0
w=25
h=25
class Shape:
    square = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,color,[x,y,w,h])
    def __init__(self,color,x,y,w,h):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        shape = Shape(white,x,y,w,h)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I want to initialize square attribute of Shape class with **init**,but I get the following error. NameError: name 'color' is not defined.
How can I initialize square attribute.

Comment: The problem is probably the line above your `__init__` method. What are you trying to accomplish there?

Also why do you have the `while` loop inside you class instead of outside of it?

Comment: `square = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,color,[x,y,w,h])` is executed when the `class` is defined, not when the instance is created. Where should `color` come from?

Comment: This is a snippet of code and i have created child class of Shape and  while loop is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to rewrite the code in this way: Just store the color and a `pygame.Rect` in the `Shape` class and give it a `draw` method. It makes no sense to have your main loop inside of the `Shape` class. Now you can create as many shapes as you want and draw them in the while loop.

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()
WHITE = pygame.Color('white')


class Shape:

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, w, h):
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, self.rect)


def main():
    game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 800))
    shape = Shape(WHITE, 0, 0, 25, 25)
    shape2 = Shape(pygame.Color('sienna1'), 100, 100, 25, 25)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    game_exit = False

    while not game_exit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True

        game_display.fill((40, 40, 40))
        shape.draw(game_display)
        shape2.draw(game_display)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

As a side note, variable names in Python should be written in `snake_case` (lower case with underscores). Also, use `sys.exit()` to quit the game.

Answer (score 1):

your **init** method runs whenever you create an object of type Shape, e.g.:

```
shape = Shape(white,x,y,w,h)
```

Then the **init** method runs with the arguments you've specified passed as parameters in that method.

With your code written as it is, you're not ever executing that particular line. Try dedenting the while loop so it's not in the class definition. Or, just to test it out, try initializing the class just as a test by running that particular line, shape = Shape(white, x, y, w, h), separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. Hope this helps..

```
import pygame
import time

class Shape:

    def __init__(self,color,x,y,w,h):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

    def draw_rect(self, gameDisplay):
        square = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,self.color,
                                  [self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h]
                                  )
        while not gameExit:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()              
                    quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

def main():

    pygame.init()
    white = (255,255,255)
    red = (255,0,0)

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((600,800))
    gameExit = False

    x=0
    y=0
    w=25
    h=25

    sobj = shape(white,0,0,25,25)
    sobj.draw_rect(gameDisplay)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```